# Symfony 5 Installation on Windows 10 keeps running old version

Tags: windows, symfony, symfony5

I downloaded and ran "setup.exe" from https://symfony.com/download.
Installation seemed to run well.

Calling

```
symfony --version
```

results in

```
Symfony Installer version 1.5.11
```

There might be installed an old Symfony version on the system - however I cant find any hint on where it actualy runs the old exectuable from (nothing obvious in System Path).
Also - shouldn't this installer just update the symfony version running?

If I download the current symfony exectuable "symfony_windows_amd64.exe" from the same page as stated at the top and run

```
[pathToExecutable]/symfony_windows_amd64.exe -V
```

it states

```
Symfony CLI version v4.12.0 (Tue Jan  7 16:14:26 CET 2020)
```

which I expect to happen when just running "symfony".

Comment: The installer and the CLI tool are two completely different tools IIRC

Comment: @Jean OK. But when calling "symfony new test_project --full" I get "[RuntimeException] The "--full" option does not exist." - I just followed the public site here though: https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup.html

Comment: @Jean The actual problem is, that calling "symfony" or "symfony.exe" from any location results in the INSTALLER to be called - but it should actualy call the created symfony exectuable. I do not find any reason for doing this though. It might be related to an old installation. But how do I get rid of the old exectuable path def (I do not find any!)

Comment: I just figured that it makes a difference to call "symfony.exe" or just "symfony"... that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jean states the CLI and the installer are different things.
calling "symfony" is different from calling "symfony.exe". That's all.